# Updating existing users with an Authlogic single_access_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authlogic, migration

I currently use Authlogic in a web-app to handle user authentication, but have now decided to create a limited API which would seem to require the use of a single_access_token.
My question is, how can I apply the migration to existing users?

I thought using something like

```
 add_column :users, :single_access_token, :string
 User.reset_column_information
 User.find(:all) do |c|
   c.update_attribute :single_access_token, *****
 end
```

I don't know if this is the best way, or what to put in place of the ***** to generate a token for all already-registered users.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think

```
User.all.each{ |x| x.reset_single_access_token! }
```

is what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks for that! I wasn't too far off, but that's exactly what I needed. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Might be quicker if you have a lot of users:

```
User.find_each do |user|

  tok = Authlogic::Random.friendly_token

  str = "UPDATE users SET single_access_token = '#{tok}' WHERE id = #{user.id}"

  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.update_sql(str)

end
```